# Как офоромить код в виде функции?

Tags: c++

Задание: Вывести длину строки, вводные данные - массив символов, выводные - целое число. Напишу код, который у меня вышел. Не могу понять, как оформить это в виде функции. Вот подсказки, которые дал препод:
"Передай указатель на массив строки
Обратно передаешь значение strlen(str)
И в главной функции его выводишь уже"

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[80];
    cout<<"длина строки:";
    gets(str);
    cout<<"Длина строки:"<<strlen(str)<<" символов"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не очень понял проблемы. Но если действительно нужно сделать "копию" встроенной функции strlen, то пожалуйста:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstring>

int get_strlen(char* _str) {
    // Функция, возвращающая длину строки
    if (_str != NULL)
        return strlen(_str);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[80];
    cout << "Длина строки: ";
    cin >> str; // Либо gets_s(str);
    cout << "Длина строки:" << get_strlen(str) << " символов" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```